# How can I made this footer ad in blogger to open for unique visitor only?

Tags: html, css, json, blogger, sticky-footer

I want to know what can I do to this "footer ad code" to make it open for unique visits to my blog only and when a visitor chooses to go to the next page within the same blog footer ad doesn't show if the user has already closed it previously.

In other words, If a visitor comes to my page and closes this footer ad then it doesn't have to show if that same user visits my other blog post or page from the same website without leaving.

```
<style>
.Arpian-ads {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 70px;
    max-height: 90px; /* modify as per your website design*/
    padding: 5px 0;
    box-shadow: 0 -6px 18px 0 rgba(9,32,76,.1);
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in;
    transition: all .1s ease-in;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    z-index: 20;
}

.Arpian-ads-close {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 12px 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: -30px;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    box-shadow: 0 -6px 18px 0 rgba(9,32,76,.08);
}

.Arpian-ads .Arpian-ads-close svg {
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    fill: #000;
}

.Arpian-ads .Arpian-ads-content {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
</style>


<div class='Arpian-ads' id='Arpian-ads'>
    <div class='Arpian-ads-close' onclick='document.getElementById(&quot;Arpian-ads&quot;).style.display=&quot;none&quot;'>
        <svg viewBox='0 0 512 512' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
            <path d='M278.6 256l68.2-68.2c6.2-6.2 6.2-16.4 0-22.6-6.2-6.2-16.4-6.2-22.6 0L256 233.4l-68.2-68.2c-6.2-6.2-16.4-6.2-22.6 0-3.1 3.1-4.7 7.2-4.7 11.3 0 4.1 1.6 8.2 4.7 11.3l68.2 68.2-68.2 68.2c-3.1 3.1-4.7 7.2-4.7 11.3 0 4.1 1.6 8.2 4.7 11.3 6.2 6.2 16.4 6.2 22.6 0l68.2-68.2 68.2 68.2c6.2 6.2 16.4 6.2 22.6 0 6.2-6.2 6.2-16.4 0-22.6L278.6 256z' />
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class='Arpian-ads-content'> Place your Ad Code </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with CSS only. You can achieve this by setting a cookie / localstorage if the ad-container was closed. Cookies are persistent even if the browser is closed. If the visitor navigates to a different page, you can first check if the cookie is set, and if it is not set you can display the ad.

Example code:

```js
const ad = document.getElementById('#Arpian-ads-close');
const wasVisible = window.localStorage.get('adShown');

/**
 * remove the ad if the user closed it
 */
if(!wasVisible){
  ad.remove();
}

/*
 * add an eventListener to add the key into the localStorage
 */
ad.addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.localStorage.set('adShown', true);
  ad.remove()
});
```